# kendo grid with textarea autocomplete & highlighting

Tags: kendo-ui, autocomplete, kendo-grid, highlight

How can I create a textarea autocompleter with highliter for the word to search in a Kendo Grid table?
Since long texts often have to be used several times, it would be helpful to suggest existing texts with an autocompleter. To select them. To better recognize the text, a highlighter in the proposed text would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working but not perfect solution: https://dojo.telerik.com/EDiDoRiw/8
Gladly better ideas at any time.